# Projection of $\log(x)$ on $(x,x^2)$

Tags: probability, statistics

For a positive random variable $X$, is it true that $\mathrm{cov}(X,\log(X))>0$ and $\mathrm{cov}(X^2,\log(X))<0$, where $\mathrm{cov}(X,Y)$ denotes the covariance between any $X$ and $Y$?

The reason I ask: I am considering a linear regression of $\log(X)$ on $X$ and $X^2$ and I would expect that the coefficients have the above signs based on the concavity of the function $\log(x)$ for $x>0$. In fact, I would not expect the signs of the above covariances to depend on the distribution of $X$.

My attempt: I have tried writing $$\log(X)=\log(x_0)+\frac{1}{x_0}(X-x_0)-\frac{1}{2x_1^2}(X-x_0)^2$$ for all $x_0$ and some $x_1$ in $\mathbb R^+$. I end up with expressions for $\mathrm{cov}(X,\log(X))$ and $\mathrm{cov}(X^2,\log(X))$ that depend on the distributional properties $\mathbb VX$, $\mathbb VX^2$ and $\mathrm{cov}(X^2,X)$, where $\mathbb VY$ denotes the variance of a random variable $Y$. I'm not sure if this approach is correct, but it seems to show that the signs of $\mathrm{cov}(X,\log(X))$ and $\mathrm{cov}(X^2,\log(X))$ can be positive or negative depending on the distribution of $X$.

Comment: Can you give any examples where $\mathrm{cov}(X^2,\log(X)) \lt 0$ (for a positive random variable $X$)?  Or where (if $X$ takes at least three values) where the regression coefficient of $X^2$ is positive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since for positive $x,y$ you have $x \lt y \iff x^2 \lt y^2 \iff \log(x) \lt \log(y)$, you will find  $\mathrm{cov}(X^2,\log(X)) \gt 0$ for positive $X$ (if there is a covariance and $X$ is not almost always constant).  The actual value will depend on the distribution of $X$.

So when you do the calculations for a linear regression of $\log(X)$ on $X^2$, the coefficient of $X^2$ will be positive.

But when you do the calculations for a linear regression of $\log(X)$ on **$X$ and** $X^2$, you should not be surprised if you find the coefficient of $X^2$ is negative, considering your convexity point.

Comment: The distinction between the signs of $\mathrm{cov}(X,\log(X))$ and $\mathrm{cov}(X^2,\log(X))$ and the signs of the coefficients in a linear regression on **both** $X$ and $X^2$ allowed me to show the result. I guess I still don't completely understand why the covariance between two increasing functions of $X$ is necessarily positive when it exists, but this is something I could look up.